# Signing A User Out of Google When They Log Out of My App

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-signin

I have a React app that allows users to login to the app via signing into their Google account.

Here's my logout function.  Removes the token that was stored in local storage. Pushes user to the login page, but, when the GoogleSignIn button re-renders, the button state indicates "Signed in with Google".  And I want that state to say "Sign in With Google".  Which would mean they were signed out in this here function:

```
const logOut = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        //LOG USER OUT OF GOOGLE ACCOUNT AS WELL
       
        history.push('/login');
    }
```

So what additional code do I need to insert here?
Thanks,
Ironman

Comment: You also need to show what libraries you are using. Logging out would simply look like await GoogleLibrary.signout()

Comment: Google is not going to allow a third party app to sign a user out of Google.  Just imagine the chaos that would cause.   You can only sign the user out of your own app.  Have you checked https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/automatic-sign-in-sign-out?hl=en